# How to get data from multiple tables from single sqlite database in one query for iOS application?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite

I'm working on an application where i need to get the details from sqlite database.
The database consists of multiple tables. I need to pass a global id to fetch the records related to one another in the database from multiple tables (like a relational database)

I don't know how to fetch the related records from database and display it in a master detail table controller.

Please provide with possible solution

Comment: Have you ever heard of joins?

Comment: joins will get a single table of related records

Comment: @user3563122 Joins are mostly used to get related data from multiple tables, not a single table.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry -- misunderstood then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example lets say you got **Table1** with fields **x1, x2, x3, a**. say you got **Table2** contains your id(global id)**g**, and a foreign key relation with Table1's field '**a**' and its field z1, z2, z3.

```
Table1--->x1, x2, x3, a
Table2--->g, z1, z2, z3, a
```

Now we are gonna fetch the contents of Table1 based on the id 'g' of Table2.

```
SELECT t1.x1, t2.x2, t3.x3, t3.a FROM Table t1, Table t2 WHERE t1.a = t2.a AND t2.g = g
```

In "t2.g = g" 'g' is the global id you are holding. good luck in learning joints.

Comment: In sqlite Database how to create a foreign key ??

Comment: CREATE TABLE Table2
(
g TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,
z1 TEXT, z2 TEXT, z3 TEXT, a TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (a)REFERENCES Table1(a)
)

Comment: @user3563122 - http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html and I do recommend that you be familiar with Create, Select, Insert, Update, delete queries and related Clauses before learning joins.